# Nginx Nextjs Strapi on EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, strapi

I tryed to launch my NextJs + strapi app on EC2 following [strapi documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/nginx-proxy), also went to [github topics](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/8487) searching for help and it doesnt work,
my nextjs project is working well and doesnt have problems, but my strapi app doesn't pass the https reversed proxy, the last config I did is this one in the image, also I tryed with separated files but still not working, but even with the separated files the nextJs app works well the only issue is the strapi does not[image: ngingx config]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to add "url" param to config/server.js.

```
url: 'http://YOUR_WEBSITE',
```

https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/server